# Differences between lists of items and list of items

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I was thinking about API path like `.../lists/items?listId=1,2,3` to get a response like below.

```json
// Map<Integer, List>
{
  1: [
    {
      "field": "item1"
    },
    {
      "field": "item11"
    }
  ],
  2: [
    {
      "field": "item2"
    },
    {
      "field": "item22"
    }
  ],
  3: [
    {
      "field": "item3"
    },
    {
      "field": "item33"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```json
// List<Object>
{
  [
    {
      "field": "item1"
    },
    {
      "field": "item11"
    },
    {
      "field": "item2"
    },
    {
      "field": "item22"
    },
    {
      "field": "item3"
    }
    {
      "field": "item33"
    },

  ]
}
```

But at the same time, I thought that the api path could be used to express to get following payload.

```json
// List<List<Object>>
{
  [
    {
      "field": "item1"
    },
    {
      "field": "item11"
    }
  ], 
  [
    {
      "field": "item2"
    },
    {
      "field": "item22"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "item3"
    },
    {
      "field": "item33"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there correct answer for three cases above to write REST API path? If not, it would be appreciate to share your experience. Thanks.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer. I find the first option to be the most intuitive tho. You should choose based on how you need to work with the data after receiving it. Eg. use the second if you don't care about the indices of the items, use the first if you later need to get a specific element etc.

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker Thank you for sharing your opinion! It really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the first method.

- The second is the worst, since you have to divide again the lists clientside, which is useless. JSON can send them separately
- The third could be used, but you would have to recreate the connection id/list, since lists don't have a key.

The map method maintains the connection id/list and separate all the lists